# Outlook 2010 - not running script (gmail MAPI account)

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a subroutine to do some work when an email with a specific subject arrives.

```
Sub ReplySpecial(objInMail As MailItem)
```

I can see the script when I select "run a script" as the option of what to do when the email matches the subject.

I put a break at the very first line of the code:

```
blnFirstName = False
```

But it never gets to the break, making me think it's not running the script.

I then changed the rule to trap every incoming email, and then look at the subject to see if I want to work on it.  Again, the same outcome - it never stops on the break.

I went to the Trust Center and enabled macros with "run all macros" and in email security "allow script in shared folders" and "allow script in public folders", just to see if I could get to the subroutine.

Again, nothing.

I've seen the posts on Outlook 2007, and have tried several of the recommendations, with no success.

As stated in the subject, this is run on a Gmail MAPI account.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and searching, I could not find a solution to this issue.

As a workaround, and since this was the only macro I had, I deleted the vbaproject.otm file and started over.

For whatever reason, it is now running the macro.